# 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: php, git, github, exec

I added path variables and git is working perfect on shell/terminal but when i try to use php exec on XAMPP server i get this error.

```
 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

my php code is here:

```
<?php 
  echo shell_exec("git pull https://github.com/Leadera/ecoman_repo.git 2>&1");
?>
```

when i make git pull request from cmd it works but in browser i get an error. What should it be the problem?

Regards,
Tuna

Answer (score 3):

`shell_exec` search for `git` command in XAMPP directory, you should use absolute path to git

```
<?php 
  echo shell_exec("/bin/git pull https://github.com/Leadera/ecoman_repo.git 2>&1");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alexandre's answer has solved the issue but i find another way to do it.

i used

> set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin 
>   (in windows)

code to add path to xampp in xampp command panel.
It also solved my problem.

Comment: I thought you were on Linux

Comment: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c2ba306e536fdf878271f7fe636a147ff37326ad\bin